# Is there any way to debug woocommerce - zapier feeds?

Tags: woocommerce, zapier

I have a staging Woocommerce site with the Zapier plugin. I've set up the Zapier end with the appropriate webhook url. The Woocommerce page indicates "This Zapier Feed is active and ready to receive real data.". I've input a few test orders and I have the order data in Woocommerce to prove it. But on the Zapier side nothing appears to have gone through. When I look at the usage history, there is nothing. I've double checked the webhook url in Woocommerce with what is in my Zap. There is only log entry and that doesn't appear relevant (error on call to undefined function pll_current_language)

Woocommerce version: 4.0.1
Woocommeerce Zapier Integration: 3.8
Woocommerce Zapier version: 1.9.6

Is there anything I can look at, at either end that will tell my why my order data isn't getting through?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, the best way to debug this is to get in touch with Zapier support (https://zapier.com/contact-us). They've got debugging tools what will help with this sort of thing.